# MVVM architecture and computations on data before presentations

Tags: architecture, mvvm

I have an android app in which I am trying to follow the MVVM arcitecture.

I have a `Room` database, abstracted by a `Repository` class that has methods like `getAllData()` which I use in my `*ViewModel` classes.

Now I want to quiery the data in the database, namely `getAllData()`, then filter, group and transform the data in different ways before presenting it as a chart.

My question is from an architectural perspective, and according to MVVM pattern, who should be responsible for doing the transformations and computations on the data?

I thought to put them in the `ViewModel` class where after loading the data, one can start processing it (of course both done asynchronously with respect to the main UI thread).

Is this approach *sane* ? If not, is there a more scalable and more maintainable approach ?

Comment: Your approach sounds fine and aligns well with the MVVM pattern. What I would be concerned with is ensuring that you handle asynchronous operations properly to avoid blocking the main UI thread and causing performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *"filtering, grouping and transforming the data in different ways"* or *"computations"* for this purpose are only required for this specific viewmodel, and nowhere else, they can be part of the `ViewModel`.

Still, there might be parts of this logic which could fit more natural into domain objects within the model layer. For example, when you are going to filter a list of domain objects by some derived attribute which requires some calculation, you may find it beneficial move the attribute together with the calculation from the viewmodel into the domain object (maybe triggered on demand, when someone requests the attribute value). Indicators for this can be

- easier testability of the logic in stake
- the attribute fits well to the overall abstraction of the domain object
- reusability in other places of your application.

Hence, instead of making the decisions for those responsibilities up-front, consider to develop them over time. Maintainability isn't achieved by making all design decisions just once and then set them in stone, it is achieved by keeping your software changable, refactorable and testable.

Comment: "_instead of making the decision of those responsibilities up-front, consider to develop them over time_ "... I think this is really valuable advice. Thank you for the answer.